# Restrict PHP file if user is not logged in?

Tags: php, authentication, session

I'm trying to prevent not signed in users to my webpage access to a certain file. I have this if statement at the top of the file I want to have restricted access.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION['user']) && $_SESSION['user'] == true) {
        echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['user'] . "!";
    } else {
         echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
         header ('index.php');
    }
 ?>
```

The thing is that if I'm signed in I do get the "Welcome to members area". And if I'm not signed in I get echo "Please log in first to see this page. However the HTML in the restricted is still showing. The user name and password are stored in a MySQL database.

Comment: What `HTML ... is still showing`? I don't see any HTML in your code.

Comment: `header ('index.php'); exit();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to reverse the order that you do this, so you don't have to contain all of your code in a block, and you can kill your page if the user is not logged in.

```
session_start();

//empty does both of the checks you are doing at once
//check if user is logged in first
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])) {

    //give error and start redirection to login page
    //you may never see this `echo` because the redirect may happen too fast
    echo "Please log in first to see this page.";
    header('Location: index.php');

    //kill page because user is not logged in and is waiting for redirection
    die();
}

echo "Welcome to the member's area, " . $_SESSION['user'] . "!";

//more page code here
```

Comment: Will the user see the "Please log in..." before the browser loads the new page(index.php)?

Comment: @TorbjörnStabo No, I mentioned in the comments in the code that they may not see it because the reload could happen too fast. The proper way to handle this would be to add a GET parameter (or session variable, or browser cookie) to/before the redirect and show the error on the page the user is redirected to.

Comment: Is does indeed restrict me from entering the page. However now i can't enter it at all even though im logged in. Any ideas whats wrong here?

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE db_username='$username' AND  db_password='$password';";
    $result = $link->query($sql) or die ("Connection lost");

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
        $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
        header("Location: admin.php");
    }

    else {
        //header("Location: index.php");
        echo "NOPE";
    }
}

Comment: @Niqqo Do you still have `session_start();` at the top? Also, do you have `session_start();` on the page where you are setting `$_SESSION['user']`? If so, your login must be failing or the variable is never set.

Comment: I somehow removed the session_start(); from the resitricted page thats why the session variable was not following along.

Thanks a lot for the quick answers and help! THANKS GUYS <3